# Ошибка в установке пакетов

Tags: linux

[image: Скрин ошибки]

Установил я гимп, и после него невозможно установить другие пакеты\приложения...
Гуглил, была у человека такая же проблема, но ответа там так и не нашел..(
Удалить его тоже не получается. Ни через терминал, ни через графическую модель.
Может кто сталкивался?

Comment: начните с удаления пакета `libgimp3.0`

Comment: у тебя конфликтуют файлы из пакета `libgimp3.0` и `libgimp2.0` ... удали один из них и сделай так, чтобы он не подтягивался по зависимостям... в принципе такого происходить не должно — их одновременная установка должна предотвращаться взаимными блокировками, но т.к. ты, судя по всему, устанавливаешь их из ppa, то это всё на их совести... чтобы решить проблему «для всех» спишись с мейнтейнерами этих ppa'шек и попроси добавить конфликт в метаданные пакетов… ЗЫ: приводи текст текстом, а не картинкой...

Comment: @Fat-Zer
sudo apt remove libgimp3.0
 gimp : Зависит: libgimp3.0 (>= 2.99.1+om~19-0ubu18.04.4~ppa) но он не будет установлен
        Зависит: libgimp3.0 (<= 2.99.1+om~19-z) но он не будет установлен
 gimp-data : Зависит: libgimp3.0 (= 2.99.1+om~19-0ubu18.04.4~ppa) но он не будет установлен
 xsane : Зависит: libgimp2.0 (>= 2.4.0) но он не будет установлен
E: Неудовлетворённые зависимости. Попытайтесь выполнить «apt --fix-broken install», не указывая имени пакета (или указав решение).

Comment: @Fat-Zer
также попробовал удалить libgimp2.0 sudo apt remove libgimp2.0 Чтение списков пакетов… Готово Построение дерева зависимостей Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово Пакет «libgimp2.0» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён Вы можете запустить «apt --fix-broken install» для исправления этих ошибок. Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости: xsane : Зависит: libgimp2.0 (>= 2.4.0) но он не будет установлен E: Неудовлетворённые зависимости. Попытайтесь выполнить «apt --fix-broken install», не указывая имени пакета (или указав решение). 
apt --fix-broken не помогает

Comment: @Nik, добавить код в вопрос можно с помощью серенькой кнопочки [edit]... я не гуру разрешения зависимостей в бубунте, но из того что я вижу, самое простое будет — заодно временно удалить xsane... ЗЫ: ИМХО конфликты проще будет разрешать из aptitude'а...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Спасибо, все дело было в xsane...щас столько пакетов обновилось LOL (162) 
При установке xsane обратно, возникают снова ошибки с gimp..

Comment: если точнее, то всё дело в том, что ты устанавливаешь dev-версию `gimp3` из какого-то стороннего ppa... если это сознательное действие, то см. первый комментарий и пожалуйся мейнтейнеру ppa о конфликте... если нет, то просто установи версию gimp'а из основных репов... и, возможно, удали ppa...